# Most concise way for derivation of$~|x+y|\geq|x|-|y|~$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I want to derive the following inequality.

$$\left|x+y\right|\geq\left|x\right|-\left|y\right|\tag{1}$$

My tries for it are as following.

$$|x+y|\leq|x|+|y|~~\leftarrow~~\text{I omit derivation of it here}\tag{2}$$

$$|x|-|y|\leq|x|+|y|~~\leftarrow~~\text{obvious}\tag{3}$$

I've been got stucked from here.

I need your wisdom.

Comment: Should I write derivation of ieq2?

Comment: Apply the triangle inequality conveniently as follows:
$$|x| = |x + y - y| \leq |x + y| + |y| \Rightarrow |x| - |y| \leq |x +y|$$

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia This way may be the simplest.

Comment: $|x+y|+|-y|\ge |x+y+-y|$

Comment: @electricalapprentice you can also prove that:

$$||x| - |y|| \leq |x + y|$$

by squaring both sides. Since $|x| - |y| \leq ||x| - |y||$, the desired result holds as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|x|=|x+y-y|\tag{1}$$

$$=\left|(x+y)+(-y)\right|\leq|(x+y)|+|(-y)|\tag{2}$$

$$\therefore~~|x|\leq|(x+y)|+|y|\tag{3}$$

$$\therefore~~|x|-|y|\leq|x+y|~~\leftarrow~~\text{QED}\tag{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to approach it:
\begin{align*}
xy \geq -|xy| & \Longleftrightarrow 2xy \geq -2|xy|\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x^{2} + 2xy + y^{2} \geq x^{2} - 2|xy| + y^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x + y)^{2} \geq |x|^{2} - 2|x||y| + |y|^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow |x + y|^{2} \geq (|x| -|y|)^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow |x + y| \geq ||x| - |y||
\end{align*}

Once $||x| - |y|| \geq |x| - |y|$, the claimed result holds.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The posted question reduces to proving that

$$|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|.$$

One method is:

- $|a+b| = (a+b)$ or $|a+b| = -(a+b),$ by definition.
- $a \leq |a|, b \leq |b| \implies (a+b) \leq |a| + |b|.$
- $-a \leq |a|, -b \leq |b| \implies -(a+b) \leq |a| + |b|.$